# Counting values in a Python array

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm so close to figuring this thing out, but I must be looking right past the solution. This program is meant to receive temperature values in Celsius, convert them to Fahrenheit, and then count the number of "cool", "warm", and "hot" days. I've got the first two parts of this problem figured out, but for whatever reason, my program isn't counting the number of each kind of day correctly.

```
temperature_list = []

value = int(input("Number of temperatures to enter: "))

for i in range(value):

    #We now collect the values

    t = int(input("Enter temperature: "))

    temperature_list.append(t)

print("Your entered temperatures in Celsius are: ", temperature_list)

#Next up is to print those temperatures in Fahrenheit, which we'll do in a batch
f_list = list()
f = [t*1.8 + 32 for t in temperature_list]
f_list.append(f)
fint = int(f[0])


cooldays = 0
hotdays = 0
for f in f_list:
    if fint > 65 :
        cooldays = cooldays + 1
    if fint < 80 :
        hotdays = hotdays + 1
print("Your temperature in Fahrenheit is: ", f[:])
warmdays = (len(f_list) - (cooldays + hotdays))
print(cooldays)
print(hotdays)
print(warmdays)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing, here?

Comment: You're using `fint` in your loop for your conditionals when you should probably use `int(f)`

Comment: You logic also allows both `cooldays` and `hotdays` to occur in the same day, making your warmdays not valid

Comment: I think you did the > and < in the wrong directions. You are checking if colds days are more that 65 and hot days are less than 80 which doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: You mentioned incorrect counts. Can you tell us the current output and the expected. Don't forget to tells us the input

Comment: Grand J, you're absolutely right. I redid the lines so often that I neglected to check which way the signs were facing! Replacing "fint" with "f" gave me the usual "'<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'" error, though.

Comment: As for counts, I entered three basic. 1 Celsius, 15 C, and 100 C.

Comment: The loop is `for f in f_list`, but inside the loop you're comparing to `fint` which is always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you are checking fint with the threshold value for every iteration. Instead you want to check it against each value in `f_list`.

Secondly, depending on your requirements, you also probably need to change your conditions. Like for example 66 is greater than 65 and also less than 80. So it will increment both... Please revise your conditions.

Third,`f = [t*1.8 + 32 for t in temperature_list]` makes `f` a list of floats. You append this to another list, `f_list`. Essentially, your f_list is now a 2D matrix. For example: `[[65,66,68.2, 98.3]]` Note the double square braces...
You could just assign the temperatures directly to `f_list`, instead of creating an intermediate variable `f`

```py
f_list = [t*1.8 + 32 for t in temperature_list]
```

```py
for f in f_list:
    if f < 65 :
        cooldays = cooldays + 1
    elif f > 80 :
        hotdays = hotdays + 1
```

Comment: How is that different to the question?

Comment: Ah nvm me I didn't immediately notice the int part being removed

Comment: the first is `f` variable in the for loop. Making other edits...

Comment: Why did you change it to ```>= 65 and <  80```? It was fine before as it is two ifs and not ```if elif```. I think the previous one better matched the OPs question as we don't know what values are expected

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood... Please check the edits...

Comment: I think we need the OPs opinion here for more clarity. Note that OP casts `fint` to an int.

Comment: There is another issue. `f_list` is a 2D array

Comment: I think I could make the >= and < option work, but I split those apart mostly due to preference. It seemed easier to just have the warm days be the remainder, neither hot nor cool.

Comment: Are cool days less than 65? and hot days > than 80?

Comment: Correct. Cool is < 65, hot is > 85 for this exercise.

Comment: Then your conditions are wrong... Think about them till I make the edit...

Comment: This solved it! I needed to turn some of the signs around, but removing the 2D matrix and just using the values worked like a charm! Thank you so much.